# Document Request & Response Headers in WebAPI

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api-helppages

I've developed a WebAPI service which passes Request & Response headers for each controller (globally). Does the WebAPI HelpController support documentation of these, through HttpResponseMessage and Requests?

Example Request Headers;

> Content-Type: application/xml; charset=utf-8

Example Response Headers;

> X-Rate-Limit-Remaining: 1000
>
> X-Rate-Limit-Limit: 1000

Comment: Did you have any luck with this? If you did it would be valuable to add your findings as an answer to your question.